# How to play song with all page? with refreshing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jplayer of jquery. When i click other link on my web (when page is refreshing) song must be continue to play but its reseting...
my JS code is...

```
 new jPlayerPlaylist({
            jPlayer: "#jplayer_1",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jplayer_container"
        }, [
            {
                title:"Your Title 1",
                mp3:"/path/to/music.mp3"
            },    
            {
                title:"Your Title 2",
                mp3:"/path/to/more-music.mp3"
            }
        ], {
            preload : "auto",
            swfPath: "mp3js",
            supplied: "mp3",
        });
```

Comment: how do you mean without page refresh? what is the problem at the moment? do you mean to play the next song?

Comment: yes song must be continue to play but its reseting..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cookie to save the current moment of the song with [Audio.currentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Seeking_through_media). If the user leaves the page, add the current position in the cookie, then when he arrives on a new page, extract the time from the cookie and place the music at the right moment.

Note that it may causes a "throttle" in track depending of the client's connection speed. It is possible to do that in AJAX too but I don't know how exactly...